# Serial port communication tutorial

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, serial-port, mingw

I'm trying to write a C++ program that reads a stream of data from a measurement device through an RS-232 serial port and translates it into a readable format. I never coded serial port communication before.

**Question:** Does anyone have a useful, easy to understand **link** or a **tutorial** that might help?

**Constraints:**

- Programming language: C++
- OS: Windows (XP) 32 bit
- Compilers: MinGW (for prototyping), Eclipse (final version)

**This means:**

- **NO** Visual Studio
- **NO** Borland,
- **NO** Code Blocks
- **NO** Blodshed DevC++

Comment: Are you looking for an RS-232 coms DLL?

Comment: I'm looking for some code for reading stuff through a serial port (RS-232) that a total beginner could understand.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Win32 APIs work with handles to communication ports. (In fact the overlapped APIs even worked on Windows 9x/ME!)

Comment: Great, can you show me a tutorial for this? So far I've only seen libraries and function descriptions.

Comment: I found this page on MSDN, it seems to be pretty thorough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the boost libraries, there are facilities for doing serial port I/O in boost::asio.  The documentation can be a bit cumbersome, but when you get down to brass tacks it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I never heard of this. Can you post any links to some tutorials?

Answer (score -2):

At [bbdsoft](http://www.bbdsoft.com/win32.html) you can download a good functioning example of a C++ class for using the serial port. Still works great!